# I make a change to one deployment slot and the change is immediately applied to the other deployment slot?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cicd

I created my Wordpress on app service using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-wordpress?wt.md_id=searchAPI_azureportal_inproduct_rmskilling&sessionId=19219dd720cc4cbf970791f07139bdf4

and then migrated my wordpress site over with the all-in-one plugin.

As the links above say, my app is a linux web app which means that autoswap is not a feature.

My current understanding of deployment slots, is that you create them by cloning your app settings, and then you have a staging site that you can change before swapping it with your production site. This should mean that they are isolated from each other immediately upon creation.

My problem: When creating my deployment slots, any changes made in one is also changed in the other.

From Research, this could mean that my deployment slots are pointed towards the same database and are therefore not isolated. This is most likely due to the database name/pass/user are all stored in the production slot as application settings which get cloned to the other deployment slots.

My Question: Does this mean that if I wanted to use deployment slots, I'd have to incur the cost of creating a separate database and endpoints for my blob storage and CDN, for every deployment slot that I have? This seems a lot more complicated than my research suggests when watching others create deployment slots and reading articles about it. Since then I'd also have to worry about keeping my databases synced continuously while in videos/articles it shows that they create the slot, work on it, and swap it and the changes are made appropriately. If this is not correct, how can I fix my problem?

**Further Info: I know that for staging sites, it would be easier to look into Staging Plugins on Wordpress. However, I also just want the deployment sites to work, even if I end up going with a separate approach.

Comment: Are both sites pointing to the same database?

Comment: I cloned all the app settings, which also shows DB name/pass/user, so I am assuming with the way the app is acting that they are. 

I was under the assumption that creating the deployment slot didn't transfer over all of the content/database? Then I will need to create a new database for each deployment slot?

Comment: Creating a second database will solve the shared content issue but will create new ones, mostly how to sync changes when both databases are live and updated separately. Deployment slots might not be the best solution. You should explore WP staging plugins instead.

Comment: I added further information. I mainly just want to understand why when researching, seeing others, they just clone the app settings and the slots work as expected without having to create new databases and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the case, but can you check to see if 'autoswap' is configured in your web app by default. And if it is turned on, then turn it off. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#configure-auto-swap

Ensure that in both your production and staging slots, under Configuration > General Settings > autoswap is set to **OFF**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, however according to their docs, Linux apps and web app for containers do not have autoswap as a feature. So, unfortunately that is not my issue :(  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots